# 5x5 matrix where each element is randomly assigned 0 or 1

Tags: python-3.x

```
list = []
for row in range (0,5):
  for col in range(0,5):
    list.append(randint(0,1))
```

When I do this, I get one long list of numbers. How do I split it up into five lists with five elements each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a matrix - so append the numbers to a row, and when the row is ready add it to the matrix:

```
matrix = []
for row in range (0,5):
    row = []
    for col in range(0,5):
        row.append(randint(0,1))
    matrix.append(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension

```
from random import randint
[[randint(0,1) for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(5)]
```

or if you use NumPy

```
from numpy.random import randint
randint(0,2,size(5,5)).tolist()
```